# createjs center zoom point localtoglobal

Tags: zooming, responsive, createjs

I have a map that is set up in createjs with a responsive canvas.  What I am trying to do is make the map zoomable but also dragable.  When the map is dragged I would like to have it zoom from a specific center point.

What I think I need to do is calculate the position of the of the center point relative to the map and then set the maps regX/regY to that point(I then think I need to reset to x/y of the map to make up for the regX/Y offset.

Since the stage is scaled I'm having a hard time even figuring out the center locations because the global coordinates seem to chance with the scaling.  I've put the center point in a holder:

exportRoot.pointHolder.tmpPt

and the map is contained in:

exportRoot.map_main_sym

what I need to figure out is what is the map_main_sym local x/y value relativie(ie directly under (exportRoot.pointHolder.tmpPt.x , exportRoot.pointHolder.tmpPt.y)

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend changing the registration point when zooming. A better approach is to determine the distance from your mouse, and determine how much to translate the container/object when you scale it.

Here is a snippet from a map tool I had handy:

```
// Find the mouse point INSIDE the mapView
var point = new createjs.Point(this.stage.mouseX, this.stage.mouseY);
var localPoint = this.mapView.globalToLocal(point.x, point.y);

// Scale the Map View
if(event.wheelDeltaY > 0){ // This is part of a mousewheel event
    // zoom in
    this.mapView.scaleX = this.mapView.scaleY *= 1.3;
} else {
    this.mapView.scaleX = this.mapView.scaleY /= 1.3;
}

// Find where the original point is now
var globalPoint = this.mapView.localToGlobal(localPoint.x, localPoint.y);
// Move the map by the difference
this.mapView.x -= (globalPoint.x - point.x);
this.mapView.y -= (globalPoint.y - point.y);
```

This is just an example, I am sure there is a more pure math approach.

Cheers.